# What is Akito's Geass?

Tags: code-geass, code-geass-akito-the-exiled

He seems to be able see and talk with dead people, which can be a coincidence as he is mentally unstable.

Other than that, he shines in battle and yells "die" while fighting, and this behavior seems to spread to other Japanese as well. However, the EU commander isn't affected by this at all.

So what exactly is his Geass?

Comment: As far as I know, this hasn't been revealed as of the end of episode 2. Episode 3 doesn't come out until May 2015.

Comment: Seeing and talking to dead people is probably not a power but can be Geass code related.  People with the code seamed to be able to communicate with people in the world of C (which is the well of all consciousness).

Answer (score 2):

Akito doesn't have a Geass, but he is under a Geass.

> Akito is under the effects of a Geass that he appears to control at
>   will, allowing him to savagely kill his enemies in the battlefield. - [Codegeass.wikia.com](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Akito_Hyuga)

His eyes also don't have the Geass Sigil inside, but his pupil is encircled red like a Geass has been casted on him.

For the ability to talk to dead, I think it has something to do with him coming back from dead, maybe he defeated death somehow.